# Can globbing be applied to multiple arguments in a command?

Tags: shell, wildcards

I'm currently implementing a shell and would like to mimick the behavior of globbing according to well-known shells.

Suppose that there is a command `foo` that takes two filename arguments. That is:

```bsh
foo file1.txt file2.txt
```

is correct usage. Also suppose that we have the following files in the current directory.

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

file1.dat
file4.dat
```

Is it possible to use multiple glob arguments when executing the command in a shell (say Bash)? For instance,

```bsh
foo *.txt *.dat
```

If so, what does this even mean or evaluate to? I would like to know which combinations would be executed as in:

```bsh
foo file1.txt file1.dat
foo file2.txt file4.dat
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly possible. You better give some details about what makes you think that would be a problem.

Comment: that would evaluate to `foo file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file1.dat file4.dat` ie. 5 separate arguments will be passed to `foo`. An easy way to check is to define a `print_args(){ printf '{%s}\n' "$@"; }` function and then call it as `print_args *.txt *.dat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. You could have tried this yourself in less time than it took to ask the question.

Unix shell such as bash expand the wildcards **before** invoking the program. The program itself doesn't see the pre-expansion version of the arguments.

So in your example, `foo` will be invoked with multiple arguments, the first ones will be the expansion of `*.txt` and the last will be the expansion of `*.dat`.

Normally the expansion of `*.txt` will be a list of filenames from the current directory ending in `.txt`. If there are none then the expansion of `*.txt` is just the unchanged `*.txt`. This can be changed with the `shopt -s nullglob` and`set -f`

Comment: My problem was I didn't have a good understanding of globbing to begin with so I felt like I was getting weird results. I understand now. I though `foo *.txt *.dat` would call `foo` multiple times with each possible file combination. Now I get that it just expands the argument into a list of arguments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

expanding the glob into an array can be helpful. This will call `foo` with each pairing:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

txts=(*.txt)
dats=(*.dat)

for txt in "${txts[@]}"; do
    for dat in "${dats[@]}"; do
        foo "$txt" "$dat"
    done
done
```